# Indirectly calling addEventListener on Safari 8 gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, safari, addeventlistener

I've come across a Safari-specific bug illustrated by the example below.

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo");

// This works as expected
el.addEventListener('click', handler);

// This should be equivalent to the above, but it doesn't work.
var alias = addEventListener;
alias.call(el, 'click', handler);
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdug0zsm/) that works in Chrome and Firefox, but results in `TypeError` on Safari (8.0.7).

Any idea why?

Comment: Does it work if you try var alias = window.addEventListener; ?

Comment: I don't see why referencing the global `addEventListener` should be equivalent to referencing `el.addEventListener`.  On what premise do you base that assertion?

Comment: @NeilMunro No. @Pointy perhaps not fully equivalent, but by using `call` I bind `this` to the element in question which seems to be equivalent to `el.addEventListener` in Chrome and Firefox. Would you mind to expand?